# Working With Multiple Data Sources in Ember.js

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

So I've been working hard establishing an app, and I'd like to now integrate a third party API using it's own data adapter.  I'd like to go about this in the most re-usable way so I've registered this adapter with the proper model (**coffeescript warning**):

```
App.Store.registerAdapter 'App.Workauth', DS.GUTSAdapter.extend
```

however here's where things get tricky: I want to do a lookup based on two attributes set on the User model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  workauths: DS.hasMany 'App.Workauth'
  token: DS.attr 'string'
  ldap: DS.attr 'string'
```

```
App.Workauth = DS.Model.extend
  worker: DS.belongsTo 'App.User'
```

With both the token and ldap we can make an API request, and the adapter for Workauths looks something like this:

```
DS.GUTSAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend Ember.Evented,

  findWorkauths: (user, name, process) ->
    token = worker.token
    ldap = "#{ user.ldap }"
    $.getJSON url, \
          ldap_username: ldap, \
          ldap_auth_token: token, \
      (data, status, jqxhr)->
        workauths=( \
          gutsId:workauth.work_auth_id, \
          name:workauth.work_auth_name, \
          hours:workauth.work_auth_hours, \
          due:workauth.work_auth_due_date \
          for workauth in data).unique gutsId
        process(workauths).load()
```

If these bindings exist, shouldn't it just be as simple as creating an outlet for User.Workauths {{render 'workauths/index'}} in my templates?  Ideally I'd think that it would do the lookup at render time, using the user token and ldap from the parent view.

Thanks in advance!